# Outputting help using DragonFruit on demand

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-arguments, dragonfruit

I'm using [System.CommandLine.DragonFruit](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/wiki/DragonFruit-overview) to handle command line arguments. In the event of errors occurring in the executable I would like to output the same help text that the "--help" option automatically outputs. Is there a method I can call to output this help text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I needed exactly the same thing a couple of months ago, unfortunately couldn't find a built-in way to do it.

The workaround I found was to invoke the auto-generated class by using DragonFruit's helper method `ExecuteAssembly` with a `--help` argument.

That's what DragonFruit does behind the scenes anyway.

```
System.CommandLine.DragonFruit.CommandLine.ExecuteAssembly(typeof(AutoGeneratedProgram).Assembly, new string[] { "--help" }, "");
```